# handling '&' on-the-fly with xmllint

Tags: xml, xmllint

I have a large number of xml files to parse with xmllint. I just need to pull out the content of one or two nodes and dumb them in some new files.

I have no control over their format before they get to me.

I am trying to find a graceful way to handle characters like "&" (ampersand). They are not always escaped in the source xmls.

is there some way to handle this in a single xmllint command or do I need to prepare the xml files first?

Comment: If the files include unescaped ampersands then they're not XML, however much they may look like it.

Comment: To add to Ian's comment, you will likely need a preprocessing phase that looks at any ampersands and determines whether they need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about xmllint.
But I do suggest to use other functions to do it. Or some script like `html2text` may work too.

In my case I solved it with:

```
echo -e $(echo "$responseXml" | xmllint --xpath '/xpath/to/extract/message/text()' - 2>/dev/null | sed 's/\&#\(x..\);/\\\1/g') | iconv --from=iso88591
```

The `iconv` may be unnecessary if your xml is not in `ISO-8859-1` or if you don't want to convert it to `UTF-8`